# The value at .output must be one of: "standalone"

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to export a build folder in `next.js`.

NOTE: I'm using the experimental `App` directory.

As per the docs to export static `HTML`, I've added this configuration in `next.config.js`

```js
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
}
```

but I get the error

```
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
warn  -     The value at .output must be one of: "standalone".
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the commit mentioned by @sprintcar13 the message says:

> We can now support `next export` for `appDir` because of the new config added in #46744.

`next build` isn't exporting the static files for me, but `next export` is. You can execute it adding a new script to package.json (`"export": "next export"`), or just typing `npx next export` on your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I was just searching around for this error myself and came across your question. After poking around, I noticed the type imports section of the config file and decided to go look at the source code. Lo and behold, the latest commit [next.js#47022](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/commit/b590ec396171e440e0fb4320d7f84f10c25a0ad6) was "feat: add `output: export` support for `appDir`"

In my case my config starts by importing the config types like so, I presume you are doing the same thing:

`/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */`

So the warning appears to be a result of the config validator, not an actual issue. The commit has been merged but is not in the latest version (v13.2.4) as of today, I would assume it will be in the next version of NextJS shortly.

Relevant snippet from [next.js#47022](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/commit/b590ec396171e440e0fb4320d7f84f10c25a0ad6) :

```
packages/next/src/build/utils.ts
1350 ...
1351 +   nextConfigOutput: 'standalone' | 'export'
1352 ...
```

In the meantime, I think its safe to say there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

remove this line

```
output: 'export',
```

use this in the command line.

```
npx next export
```

This works for me.